# Copy data from one specific kafka partition

Tags: apache-kafka

Just wondering which would be the simplest way to copy data from a specific partition into a single-partition topic.

One possible use case for this would be to process old data one partition at a time during a backfilling operation in order to minimize the impact on the real-time service so to speak.

Does it make sense or are there simpler alternatives which don't require replicating the msgs between topics? For example, it would be nice that one could whitelist/filter partitions at the consumer group level but AFAIK that is not possible. In any case, the idea would be to have a reusable way of restricting to a specific partition. Reusable here means such that it does not require code changes in the services at hand (just config changes for overriding the input topic).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `consumer.assign()` method to read from one specific topic-partition. This does not use consumer groups. Then you can construct a producer for the new topic, and send data into it, and `flush` periodically. Otherwise, yes, you can use `subscribe()` and check `if (record.partition() == N)`

When you reach the end of the partition, close both clients

Comment: I was wondering if that was possible to accomplish using existing tools like kcat without any coding whatsoever, but otherwise I will implement that as described. Thanks!

Comment: kcat can work with a Unix pipe, but it assumes your data is utf8 encoded. By controlling consumer and producer yourself, you can skip serialization and use ByteArrayDesrializer, for example. The old MirrorMaker script might work as well, but it'll need a custom handler to only forward one partition